# Change default page title wordpress using filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, page-title

I am trying to change the default blog post title (Hello world) in WordPress

```
add_filter('the_title', 'modify_all_titles', 10, 2);

function modify_all_titles($title, $id) {

return 'My default page title';
}
```

As you can see it changes ALL blog posts titles.

How can I change only the default page title (The first post, or post ID1 for example)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you should use wordpress [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/)

in your case `is_single()` is the appropriate function.

to check if the current query is a post with id 1: `is_single(1)`

same thing with post's slug: `is_single('hello-world')`

your code with conditional tags:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'modify_all_titles', 10, 2);

function modify_all_titles($title, $id) {

return $id == 1 ? 'My default page title' : $title;
}
```

you can also compare `$id` with hello world's id

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this one: add_filter('the_title', 'modify_all_titles', 10, 2);

function modify_all_titles($title, $id) {

return is_single(1) ? 'My default page title' : $title;
} doesn't change the post title

Comment: Yes, it's fine now. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: ywc,,, happy to help